# Is it possible to trigger Pub/Sub event with App Engine Cron directly

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to configure cron of the App Engine to directly trigger some Pub/Sub event? All our application build on Google Cloud Functions and we are not using App Engine as a main service, but we need to run task to unlock documents every N minuets. So, direct Pub/Sub call would be perfect. But, I don't see any other options, other than to create additional script (inside App Engine) that cron will fire. Inside that script the Pub/Sub event will be fired. The current cron config looks like that

```
cron:
- description: scan for dead locks and release locks
  url: /projects/{project-name}/topics/scan-dead-locks
  schedule: every 20 mins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'direct' you mean 'direct from cron', then no. App Engine cron entries trigger endpoints in an app (script). If you want to do something with pubsub, it'll need to be done with an endpoint.